# debug node js chaincode ...?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

[This link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dzwR0dwzXNs) gives tutorial on debugging javascript chaincode in hyperledger fabric. I was able to debug my chaincode following it but recently I updated to fabric 1.2 and the peer channel list command

```
CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/home/bct/fabric-samples/basic-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp peer channel list
```

fails with:

> Fatal error when initializing core config : error when reading core
>   config file: Unsupported Config Type ""

I tried to go back to v1.1 but the problem persists. Can someone give me the complete list of configuration steps that may have been missed in tutorial video (which I was following) that make the debugging chaincode work.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, figured out that fabric sdk (https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node) has to be downloaded and configured before following the video tutorial in the question.